# Getting the current browser url in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, url-mapping

I need to get the browser URL in Grails, or particularly, a parameter off of it in the UrlMapping.

I need this in a particular circumstance, after an asynchronous call from a different controller/action, at this point, request.forwardURI has changed to the asynchronous url, while the actual browser url has remained the same.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `request` object, you can get any property of the URL (including parameters), because `request` is an implementation of [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

Comment: As I mentioned, the request url refers to the url of the asynchronous call, not the url in the browser. The browser url parameter is the one I need to access.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing an asynchronous call, just add the current browser URL as a parameter to your request.  Retrieve it via `window.location` and add it to the params passed in via your async call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep track of the current state your user is in based on URL parameters you might look into Spring Web Flow support within Grails -> http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow

Obviously this is more for stateful web apps than RIA stuff with Ajax but Web Flow does a very good job at isolating particular user operations and *might* help here as well.